# AWS cluester - understanding Internal Loadbalancer and Ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer, kubernetes-ingress, internal-load-balancer

I have a cluster in AWS which is set up as Topology=Private and has an Internal Loadbalancer. Now I'm trying to deploy an Nginx Ingress Loadbalancer for it to expose the application pods to the internet.

I am trying to understand that in such a setting what will be the role of my internal loadbalancer (which I believe is a Elastic Loadbalancer). And could I have this setup even without the internal loadbalancer? In fact, what functionality would the cluster lose without the internal loadbalancer?

Comment: In current setup without Nginx Ingress Loadbalancer, how internet traffic comes to you private load balancer ?

Comment: I have just created a cluster as a test to get familiar with aws and Ingress and Loadbalancers, no traffic yet. I'm just trying to learn the possibilities to expose a private cluster to internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to have the load balancer (ELB) for HA purpose, But place public facing ELB before the nginx controller instead of behind it. You can also do custom path routing in ALB (Layer7). Ideal setup would be

**ELB(Public with SSL termination) --> 2 Nginx Ingress Loadbalancer(for HA have 2 instances in diff subnet) --> Application Pods.**

Apart from ELB, remaining can be placed in private subnets.

Comment: So how could this be if my aws ELB is internal (private)?

Comment: If your ELB is private and exposing nginx as public facing, in that case, you will lose HA, since you are responsible for Ngnix HA. But if you have public ELB then AWS will manage the ELB HA for you.

Comment: In the case of private ELB in my aws cluster and having a public facing ingress, what would be the benefit of the internal ELB? If it is loadbalancing, the ingress could do that too, right? My second question is, if I already have an internal ELB and then deploy the ingress by following the instruction given in https://daemonza.github.io/2017/02/13/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/   , then would aws put my ingress before my ELB and I don't need to do anything about that?

Comment: You don't need the private ELB, the blog which you have mentioned suggested same approach as i did. i.e having a public ELB and Nginx Ingress behind it.

Comment: thanks @Madhan S, so in this approach the ELB will have a public IP address, but why the ingress in the blog post has a public IP address (51.232.218.155) too?

Comment: In the blog, the app servers are also having the public Ips :) for demo purpose they have created like that.